# try to apply k-fold cross validation to the ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory

Tags: keras, cross-validation

I try to apply k-fold cross validation to the cnn classification problem

let say I have a carA, carB

so I made the subfolder

> car/trainCross/fold0
>  car/trainCross/fold1
>
> car/validCross/fold0
>  car/validCross/fold1

and following code

```
model_path = '../carPrediction/model/'+ 'saved.hdf5'
for i in range(2):
    print('training->',i,' split')
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_CROPPED_PATH +'fold'+str(i),
                                                                 target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                class_mode='categorical',
                                                                seed=2019,
                                                                color_mode='rgb')
    print(VALID_CROPPED_PATH+'fold'+str(i))
    validation_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                                        VALID_CROPPED_PATH+'fold'+str(i),
                                                        target_size=(image_size,image_size),
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        class_mode='categorical',
                                                        seed=2019,
                                                        color_mode='rgb'
                                                    )
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_test,
                                                        directory=TEST_CROPPED_PATH,
                                                        x_col='img_file',
                                                        y_col=None,
                                                        target_size= (image_size,image_size),
                                                        color_mode='rgb',
                                                        class_mode=None,
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        shuffle=False
                                                    )
    try: 
        model = load_model(model_path, compile=True)
    except Exception as OSError:
        pass

    patient = 2
    callbacks1 = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patient, mode='min', verbose=1),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss', factor = 0.5, patience = patient / 2, min_lr=0.00001, verbose=1, mode='min'),
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min'),
    ]

    history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=get_steps(nb_train_sample, batch_size),
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=get_steps(nb_validation_sample, batch_size),
    verbose=1,
    callbacks = callbacks1
)
```

but not sure in this way is correct
any thought?

Comment: SKLearn has some [helpful tools](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html), and you can see how they can be implemented in code like in [this example](https://www.kaggle.com/christofhenkel/keras-baseline-lstm-attention-5-fold), 10th code snippet.

Comment: I'm just not sure this way also work for k-fold cross validation or not? can you tell?

Comment: Im doing this way because i'm using flow_from_dataframe generator. I'm not using any dataframe in this example. that is why try to implement my own k-fold cross validation example